# Rango decimales Sql server

Tags: sql-server

Hola buen dia quiero saber como puedo hacer una condicion tengo este problema cuando en una consulta resto campo1-campo2 en la condicion debo traer solo cuando hay diferencias, sin embargo existe que la diferencia a veces me sale de 0.01 o -0.01 quiero que si sale eso como resultado lo ignore tengo la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT CAMPO1-CAMPO2 FROM RESTA WHERE (CAMPO1-CAMPO2)>0
```

quiero la consulta que me traiga si la renta hubo diferencia de 0 pero si hay entre un rango de 0.01 o negativo yo ignorarlo en la consulta, lo hice usando cast para trabajar con enteros pero no me sirver

```
SELECT CAST((CAMPO1-CAMPO2) AS INT) FROM RESTA WHERE CAST((CAMPO1-CAMPO2) AS INT)>0
```

alguien que me ayude con otra forma de hacerlo

Comment: Dices: *quiero la consulta que me traiga si la renta hubo diferencia de 0*, entonces ¿por qué no pones la condición así: `WHERE (CAMPO1-CAMPO2)=0` Pues se interpeta que quieres que te muestre resultados solamente cuando la diferencia sea cero... ¿es correcto o no? Si no lo es explica mejor qué resultados quieres porque el planteamiento es un poco confuso.

Comment: lo que pasa es que a veces trae decimales la resta entonces los quiero omitir

Comment: ¿Qué quieres omitir, los decimales (redondeando) o los resultados que traen decimales? La pregunta no se entiende, pon ejemplos de los valores que serían permitidos y los que no.

Comment: ah ok a me trato de explicar tengo en el resultado 5000-5000.02 cuando se hace la renta sobran .02 si sale ese rango de decimas aun asi quiero omitirlo al igual que WHERE (CAMPO1-CAMPO2)=0

Comment: Bueno, vamos a hacer la pregunta al revés a ver si logra entenderse: **¿a partir de qué valor deben mostrarse los datos**? @DiegoTorres no se logra entender lo que pregunto aquí, en negritas. Es fundamental para que escribas una respuesta definitiva.

Comment: ok  quiero si WHERE (CAMPO1-CAMPO2)=0 trae los resultados pero si tambien sale por decima de rango 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ,0.4 ó negativos -0.1, -0.2, -0.3 ,-0.4 si es eso me trae resultado la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el valor absoluto `ABS` de la diferencia para filtrar y `CAST` para descartar los decimales

```
SELECT CAST(CAMPO1 - CAMPO2 AS INT) 
FROM RESTA 
WHERE ABS(CAMPO1 - CAMPO2) > 0.01
```

Comment: me sirve mucho como puedo hacer si quiero comparar mas rango en vez de >0.01 agregar que sea 0.02, 0.03 ?

Comment: Pues reemplazas el 0.01 por 0.02.  o ¿te refieres a algo más?

Comment: si me refiero a algo mas amigo si me sirvio mucho de hecho pero como un rango quiero no se de 0.01 al 0.30

Comment: solo que me des ese tip amigo me sirvio mucho como lo plamos pero con rango no se entre 0.01 y 0.30

Comment: Ah, creo que ya entendí, puedes cambiar `> 0.01` por `BETWEEN 0.01 AND 0.3`.

Comment: me sirvio mucho gracias queria darme cuenta yo lo hice usando cast int para que solo tomara enteros y evitar decimales, pero esta opcion me sirvio mas gracias